# Sum of array in Halide

Tags: halide

I've started learning Halide. Suppose I wanted to calculate the sum of elements in an array. Why is the following code snippet failing?

```
constexpr int N = 10;
ImageParam array(Float(32), 1);
Var x;
Func fsum("sum");
RDom i(1, N);
fsum(x) = 0.0f;
fsum(0) = array(0);
fsum(i) = array(i) + fsum(i-1); 
Buffer<float> buffer(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) buffer(i) = rand() / 100.0f;
array.set(buffer);
Buffer<float> output = fsum.realize(1);
```

The runtime error is:

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> Halide::RuntimeError: Error: Input buffer p0 is accessed at 10, which
> is beyond the max (9) in dimension 0

**UPDATE:**
I've updated the indices according to the accepted answer and put some code to check the reproducibility.

```
    constexpr int N = 10;
    ImageParam array(Float(32), 1);   
    Var x;
    Func fsum("sum");
    RDom i(1, N-1);
    fsum(x) = 0.0f;
    fsum(0) = array(0);
    fsum(i) = array(i) + fsum(i-1); 
    Buffer<float> buffer(N);
    float cppsum = 0.0f;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
        buffer(k) = (float) k;
        cppsum += k; 
    }    
    array.set(buffer);
    Buffer<float> hsum = fsum.realize(1);
    std::cout << "Halide sum: " << hsum(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C++ sum: " << cppsum << std::endl;
    //fsum.compile_to_lowered_stmt("hsum.html", {}, HTML);
```

Halide sum is 0. C++ sum is 45. I wanted to check the resulting code, but if the last line is commented out I get a

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> Halide::CompileError: Error: Generated code refers to image parameter
> p0, which was not found in the argument list.
> Argument list specified:>
> Parameters referenced in generated code: p0>
> Abort trap: 6

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that your code reads out of bounds in the input `array`. This is because the `RDom i` goes from `1` to `N+1` (`RDom` ranges in Halide are expressed as `min, extent` not `min, max`, so they go from `min` to `min+extent`). You probably mean `RDom i(1,N-1)`.